# Beckhoff Twincat how to edit tsconfig.json?

Tags: twincat-hmi

After manually applying changes to the tsconfig.json file in the Beckhoff Twincat 3 development environment, the Beckhoff development environment reverts all changes in the original state when a compilation of the project is performed.

The Beckhoff development environment should not revert all changes in the original state when a compilation of the project is performed.

Answer (score 0):

Twincat HMI is visual studio based, it uses a file tsconfig.tpl.json to store user settings, and package references.
On project build this files contents, and resolved package references are saved as tsconfig.json
So edit tsconfig.tpl.json then build the project in visual studio to get your changes in tsconfig.json